# How to get Status Message of a transaction from ethersjs

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I am trying to get Status Message return from solidity function, the message is showing in this URL

[Fail with error 'swap: User not allowed to swap!'](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xbc79749e09b8d45170026d0103b8220e0e91380eb644f09f10aed543f6bebc9a)

when I am getting the receipt from provider.getTransactionReceipt(tx) then it only gives me status 0 but not with the message in etherscan.io. Is there any way to get that message from ethers.js

[image]

check my log in console showing status: 0
[image]

Comment: Can you provide some code

Comment: The fail reason is not part of the standardized [receipt](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_gettransactionreceipt)... I found [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/70391) on ETH StackExchange, but the linked code errored "missing revert data in call exception" using your tx hash... There is a low-level way to get the message using [debug_traceTransaction](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/ns-debug#debug_tracetransaction) RPC method, looking for the `REVERT` opcode and a pointer to the storage location of the error message, but I understand this is not what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm also curious about this!